# What does "convey" mean in this sentence?

Tags: meaning, meaning-in-context, sentence

I was reading a wikipedia page and stumbled upon this sentence.

> A layman or straw man is a figure not intended to have a genuine beneficial interest in a property, *to whom such property is nevertheless conveyed in order to facilitate a transaction*.

I don't completely understand the sentence in italic, especially what it means by "conveyed".

Can anyone explain?

Comment: Does the sentence mean the straw man is transfered the property even though they will not do anything with it that benefits them?

Comment: Hi @FreeHongKong  I think the answer to your question in the comments is yes.  It would be useful to understand the context of this comment.  That would help me understand what you don't understand better.

Comment: Thank you for the explanation!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

*Convey* is a nice catch-all word meaning transfer or move (to).  If whatever is being conveyed can't be moved, like land, then convey means pass the title to.  Convey doesn't specify how it's effected—for example, by sale, gift, assignment, etc.  That part is what your example discusses.